# Show todays record, but calculate with yesterday

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show records from today, but I need to calculate difference from today and yesterday.

The select is:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM page where date(data)=CURDATE()";
```

and showing number of today is  `$rows['like'];`.

I need to show the difference, something like that: **difference=like(today)-like(yesterday)**.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: can you explain more clearly? What is expected output

Comment: i have: 
<?php
connectdb();
$sql="SELECT * FROM page where date(data)=CURDATE()";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['like'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $difference;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
i don't know how to show $difference . thanks for answers, but i'm not expert in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select a.dt, b.likes -a.likes 
 from pagelikes  a
 join pagelikes  b on a.dt = DATEdiff(DD , 1, b.dt)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(p1.like)-COUNT(p2.like) AS difference 
FROM page p1, page p2 
WHERE DATE(p1.data)=CURDATE() 
AND DATE(p2.data)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

EDIT:

```
<?
connectdb();
$sql="
SELECT p1.name,p1.like,(p1.like-p2.like) AS difference 
FROM page p1, page p2 
WHERE DATE(p1.data)=CURDATE() 
AND DATE(p2.data)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?> <tr> <td><? echo $rows['name'];?></td> <td><? echo $rows['like'];?></td> <td><? echo $rows['difference'];?></td> </tr> <?
}
?>
```

Comment: i don't know were to pot this code. in $sql='....' interogation? thanks for your answer.

Comment: when i put that code in $sql='...';, and tried to show difference, i receive an error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /index2.php on line 77, where line 77 is while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ . i tried to show difference <?php echo $rows['difference'];?>

Comment: after the `$result=mysql_query($sql)` line, insert a line `echo(mysql_error());` and you will receive an error message which may either help you or me to debug this.

Comment: Second possibility would be to post some more of your code, actually.

Comment: That is my code:

    <?
    connectdb();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM page where date(data)=CURDATE()";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><? echo $rows['name'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['like'];?></td>
    <td><? echo $difference;?></td>
    </tr>
    <? }?>

I dont know how to make $difference (like from today-like from yesterday).

Comment: is working, but shows me all records.. i want to show me only todays records with that difference that is working.